# What are the chances of me pulling this combo of m'n'ms out of a bag?

Tags: probability

So I pulled out $1$ orange, $2$ brown, $3$ green, $4$ red, $5$ blue and $6$ yellow.

[image]

I was totally mind blown and wanted to calculate the chances.

Assuming equal distribution of $m'n'ms$ in the bag.

I got as far as $\frac{21!}{6!5!4!3!2!1!} = \frac{1}{2,053,230,379,200}$.

Is that right?

I know that it doesn’t account for the possibility of different colour combinations which is OK.

Comment: How did you come up with that calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure what you worked out was the probability of getting them in this exact order from this group of m'n'ms.

I think if you want to know the probability of getting this group out of a bag, assuming equal distribution and an infinite (or near enough) bag of m'n'ms there would be $6^{21} $ permutations (6 choices for each of 21 picks), of which $ \frac {21!}{6!5!4!3!2!1!}$ ($21!$ ways to arrange with duplicates accounted for) match what you are looking at. This gives a probability of $\approx 9.4\times10^{-5} $

If you were looking at a limited bag say 10 of each colour, you would need to work out the probability of this exactly $\frac{^{10}P_1^{10}P_2^{10}P_3^{10}P_4^{10}P_5^{10}P_6}{^{60}P_{21}} $ then multiply by $ \frac {21!}{6!5!4!3!2!1!}$ which changes the probability slightly to $\approx 7.5\times10^{-5} $

Notice I chose to use permutations in all of this because they end up cancelling at the end when looking at the probabilities.